# Transaction submission times

Tags: transaction, utxo

I am building an NFT marketplace on Cardano which supports 3 wallets: Typhon, Yoroi and Nami.
I have to mint an NFT right before putiing it on sale, so I figured I need to wait for the newly minted NFT (or rather it's UTxO) to arrive at the wallet address before I build the Plutus transaction to put it on sale.

Unfortunately, sometimes wallets don't throw an error, even though the transaction submition fails. I was wondering if there is a set time which I can use as a cut-off point (as in if the UTxO didn't arrive within X amount of time after transaction was submitted - I consider the transaction as failed).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend against just waiting a pre-determined time and then assuming the transaction has been submitted.

Instead, you should only support wallets that do properly report an error when the transaction submission fails. You can also raise a bug against the wallets that do not do this, and say that your program cannot support them until they correctly report failed transaction submission.

Comment: I am not assuming that it succeeded, I am assuming it failed, if the UTxO has not arrived within a time limit

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but I still recommend that you post bug reports for wallets that do not provide appropriate feedback when a tx submission fails.